# RxJava and Retrofit handle pagination with multiple flatmaps

Tags: android, pagination, retrofit, rx-java, observable

I am using `Retrofit` with `RxJava` and I need to do following login scenerio:

1) Login user with password and get access token

2) Get user profile, 
friends(needs pagination assume 15 page), 
conversations(needs pagination assume 10 page)

All of requests at second step needs token so they depend on first step.

What I need to do is execute first step and when its done execute second step and be notified when all of 3 jobs done.

What I have right now:

First of all I am handling pagination using `concatWith` operator and its working great. For example :

```
mApi.getConversationsByPage(accessToken,page,take)
.concatMap(convResponse -> {
  if(convResponse.body().getNextPageUrl().equals("NA")) {
      return Observable.just(convResponse);
  } else {
      return Observable.just(convResponse)
      .concatWith(getConversationsAndNext(accessToken,convResponse .body().getNextPage(),take));
  }
});
```

My code :

```
mService.loginUser(email,password)
     .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
     .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
     .flatMap(tokenResponse -> {
            //login finished save token
            mService.saveUserToken(tokenResponse.body());
            //first step done go to second step
            return mService.getUserProfile(mService.getToken();
       })
     .flatMap(profileResponse -> {
         mService.saveUserProfile(profileResponse.body());
         return mService.getUserFriendsAndNext(mService.getToken(),FIRST_PAGE,TAKE_PERPAGE);
     }).doOnNext(friendResponse -> mService.handleFriendPaging(friendResponse.body().getData()))
     .flatMap(friendResponse -> {
         mService.saveAllFriends();
         return mService.getConversationsAndNext(mService.getToken(),FIRST_PAGE,TAKE_PERPAGE);
     })
     .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ConvResult>>() {
         @Override
         public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
             mDisposables.add(d);
         }

         @Override
         public void onNext(Response<ConvResult> convResponse) {
             mService.handleConvPaging(convResponse .body().getData());   
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(Throwable e) {
             //handle error
         }

         @Override
         public void onComplete() {
             //all requests done handle it
             mService.saveAllFriends();
         }
     });
```

Everything works great. I am saving user token, user profile, user friends but when its come to conversations `mService.handleConvPaging` method calling 25 times instead of 10 times.

My test method : `Mockito.verify(mService,times(10)).handleConvPaging();`

And error :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
mService.handleConvPaging();
Wanted 10 times:
-> at ........
But was 25 times.
```

So what I want to do is: get user friends and conversations independently and when all requests, pagings done get notified.

Is there any way to achieve this without using nested callbacks? Thanks in advance.

**@Edit** :

```
mService.loginUser(email,password)
            .flatMap(tokenResponse -> {
                if(tokenResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                    mService.saveUserToken(tokenResponse.body());
                    return mService.getUserProfile(mService.getUserAccessToken());
                } else {
                    return Observable.error(new Exception("login token error"));
                }
            })
            .flatMap(profileResponse -> {
                if(profileResponse.isSuccessful()) {
                    mService.saveUserProfile(profileResponse.body());
                    return mService.getUserFriendsAndNext(mService.getUserAccessToken(),1,Constants.TAKE_COUNT);
                }else {
                    return Observable.error(new Exception("login profile error"));
                }
            })
            .doOnNext(friendResponse -> {
                if(friendResponse.isSuccessful()) mService.handleFriendPaging(friendResponse.body().getData());
            })
            .ignoreElements()
            .andThen(mService.getConversationsAndNext(mService.getUserAccessToken(),1,Constants.TAKE_COUNT))
            .subscribe(onsubscribe,onnext,onerror,oncomplete)
```

If I return `Observable.error()` at `tokenResponse` section the `andThen` method is calling which I don't want that happen

And also I return this when `mService.loginUser` method called :

```
Response<UserTokenResult> tokenResultResponse = Response.error(400,mResponseBody);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem but somehow your 2 flapMap seems do not make sence for me. They don't depends on each other they just do the different behavior after you get the tokens. You should use a `share()` or a publish(selector) in this case IMHO.

Comment: My problem is my third flatmap is calling when my second flatmap called which I do not want to do. I only want to call my third flatmap once my all second flatmap paginations done.

Comment: I don't know whether this is what you want. I post my answer below.

Comment: Your code seems good for me. The only guess is something wrong with your service side. Could you please check whether `tokenResponse.isSuccessful()` return you a true or false in your case.  I did tests but all happens as I expect. :(

Comment: I tested it using assertEquals and it just returns Observable.just(response). Then I check it and return error or normal observable

Comment: @PhoenixWang when updated RxJava to 2.0.9 now it works, if I return `Observable.error()` it goes andThen too but immediately `onError` method invokes. I guess this works with 2.0.9. Let me unit test everything and I inform you

Comment: sry for repling later. Kinda busy those days. I guess it's a bug or problem with your service part because your code is perfect good for me. Instead of I helping you figure it out. You could post an issue on Github in RxJava repo. I highly doubt it's a bug for old version of RxJava 2.

Comment: yes thanks, actually I managed to solve problem. Recursion for pagination is the key. I returned `Observable.error` instead of pagination and it works now but still `andThen` method invokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your mentioned in comment, your problem is that your third flatMap should be called after the second flatMap finished. 
So I'd like to propose a solution like this:

```
    mService.loginUser(email,password)
            .subscribeOn(mSchedulerProvider.io())
            .observeOn(mSchedulerProvider.ui())
            .flatMap(tokenResponse -> {
                mService.saveUserToken(tokenResponse.body());
                return mService.getUserProfile(mService.getToken();
            })
            .flatMap(profileResponse -> {
                mService.saveUserProfile(profileResponse.body());
                return mService.getUserFriendsAndNext(mService.getToken(),FIRST_PAGE,TAKE_PERPAGE);
            })

            // do All your work with your Friends in this operator
            .doOnNext(friendResponse -> mService.handleFriendPaging(friendResponse.body().getData()))

            //his will return you a Completable
            .ignoreElements()

            //You get the signal means the upStream works are done
            .andThen(mService.getConversationsAndNext(mService.getToken(),FIRST_PAGE,TAKE_PERPAGE))
            .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ConvResult>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    mDisposables.add(d);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<ConvResult> convResponse) {
                    mService.handleConvPaging(convResponse .body().getData());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //handle error
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    //This is somehow not necessary
                    mService.saveAllFriends();
                }
            });
```

So you keep one single stream and get your work done.

`ignoreElements()` provide the ability that you only receive the terminal events(onComplete() and onError()), `andThen()` will subscribe the upStream Completable and will continue to emit items from the source you put in `andThen()`.

I tested something like

I tried something like

```
    Observable.just("A", "B", "C")
            .flatMap(x -> Observable.error(new Throwable("Eorror")))
            .doOnNext(x -> System.out.println(x))
            .ignoreElements()
            .andThen(Observable.just("New D"))
            .subscribe(x -> System.out.println("onNext" + x),
            error -> System.out.println("onError" + error),
            () -> System.out.println("END"));
```

and it's print only

```
System.out: onErrorjava.lang.Throwable: Eorror
```

with RxJava version 2.0.9

Comment: Vaow this is working man. But I want to ask you two questions. First if I got an error in any of flatmaps where do I get it , in my onError and can I terminate following flatmaps ? Also you said this is somehow not neccesary in my onComplete but it means all the flatmaps completed ?

Comment: So for the first question:

`An error event from this Completable will be propagated to the downstream subscriber and will result in skipping the subscription of the Observable.`

from Rxjava Javadoc. So you will remain that onError safety using andThen. 
For the second question. I just see you use saveAllFriends twice. If you need do it twice then it's necessary for you.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but if I return `Observable.error()` at early flatmaps the `andThen` method still invokes and I got `NullPointerException` . How can I block it when early flatmaps has an error. Or how can I block below flatmaps when a flatmap returns error.

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz I tried with my code and work well for me. Did you pass an error as an object? Or maybe consider to upgrade RxJava? I saw a related bug but not sure it's for this case : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/4957

Comment: If I really return Observable.error() at tokenResponse all the stuff never called below but andThen method is calling. I am using v2.0.9 too. I really don't know what is wrong actually whenever error comes I need to terminate all the logic

Comment: could u upload more code for this Observable.error() ？

Comment: I added my code, please can you check @Edit section